# In JMeter - Receiving 403 Forbidden - CSRF verification failed. Request aborted in Login

Tags: jmeter, http-status-code-403, csrf-token

I have recorded a scripts in Blaze meter and uploaded a jmx file and added Regular Expression Extractor

**Name of created Variable: CSRF_TOKEN

Regular Expression: Set-Cookie: csrftoken=(.+?);

Template: $1$

Match No. (0 for Random): 1**

But still am getting an error. Login is not successful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to tick "Response Headers" as the "Field to check"

   [image]
2. Make sure to add the Regular Expression Extractor [as a child](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) of the request which returns the token
3. It might be the case that the cookie is being set in one of sub-samples, if this is the case - amend "Apply to" field accordingly
4. Be aware that you can extract `csrftoken` (as well as any other cookie value) using [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide/), add it to test plan, add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```

   and you will be able to access the value as `${COOKIE_csrftoken}` where required
5. Make sure to replace recorded hard-coded value with the appropriate [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
6. In some cases post-processing may be required like [URL encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) or decoding or similar so it may be a good idea to perform the login using the browser several times and compare the value from the Set-Cookie header with the value of the next request parameter using [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)